# Table cell map engine

Tags: javascript, game

I'm designing a table cell based map design for a little game I'm building, and I was hoping I could get some cleanup pointers or design tips to "perfect" my engine's design. Basically, in the end result, you'll walk around the map one tile at a time. On any visible tile you can walk to it, but only the tile you're on will have "actions" (randomly generated).

Here is my prototype design:

```
function Map() {
    this.x;
    this.y;
}

Map.prototype = {
    move:function() {
        var new_x = this.x - 1;
        var new_y = this.y - 1;
        Map.prototype.render(new_x, new_y);
    },
    render:function(p_x,p_y) {
        //check for map boundaries
        var max_divs = 2;
        if(!p_x) p_x = 1;
        if(!p_y) p_y = 1;
        if(p_x >= 99) p_x--;
        if(p_y >= 99) p_y--;

        divs_x = max_divs + p_x;
        divs_y = max_divs + p_y;
        //create new table
        var root = document.createElement("table");
        root.id = 'root_table';
        //loop coordinates and generate surrounding cells
        for (var x = p_x; x <= divs_x; x++) {
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var y = p_y; y <= divs_y; y++) {
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                if (x <= 0 || y <= 0 || x >= 101 || y >= 101) {
                    cell.textContent = "";
                }
                else {
                    this.x = x; this.y = y;
                    cell.textContent = "("+this.x+","+this.y+")";
                    //add event handler for the click event (move)
                    cell.addEventListener("click", this.move, false);
                    cell.x = x; cell.y = y;
                    cell.className = 'map';
                }
                //add cell to row
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }
            //add row to table
            root.appendChild(row);
        }
        var main = document.getElementById("container");
        var old_table = document.getElementById('root_table')
        if(old_table) main.removeChild(old_table); 
        //remove old table, add new one
        main.appendChild(root);
    }
}

var map = new Map();
map.render();
```

And here is a current working link to my map: [zombiesss ahhhh](http://fooscript.com/zombie)

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid your code is very hard to understand.  Part of the problem is your variable naming: I'm not sure what exactly `p_x` is and what distinguishes it from the `x` that's part of the `Map` object, for example.  It also doesn't help that your comments mostly just describe the behaviour of entirely obvious single lines of code but don't describe any of the unclear aspects of your code, for instance why it is doing what it is doing.

On to more specific comments, this line of code is confusing:

```
Map.prototype.render(new_x, new_y);
```

Is there a reason you aren't using `this.render(new_x, new_y)` here, but instead calling the method directly on the prototype object?  If so, it would be best to explain it with a comment, as this is quite unusual behaviour.  Also, what are `new_x` and `new_y`, and why are they calculated in the way they are?  As far as I can see, `Map.x` and `Map.y` are never set to anything that has any particularly useful meaning.

In your inner loop in the `render` method, you repeatedly update `this.x` and `this.y`, but the values stored here are never read by code outside of the method, because they are overwritten by the next iteration of the loop before anything else can touch it.  It is unclear why you are doing this, but generally it would be better to only update them once, and to use local variables when you are calculating values for use only within a single method.

You have a number of values in your code that are seemingly related, i.e. 99 and 101 used in two different places.  It may be best to use a variable to store one of these values (I think 100 cells is the size of your map?) and derive one from the other as necessary.

**Update after clarification in comments**

Having `move` be part of the `Map` object when it isn't called in that context is confusing.  Also referring to `Map.prototype` is unlikely to be what you want to do, as it basically prevents you from ever having more than one `Map`, thus negating a key benefit of using objects at all.

Here's how I would handle it: I wouldn't declare the event handler as a separate function at all, but instead declare it inline when I set the event handler.  I would also make sure it had a variable in scope that refers to the `Map` object, so it doesn't need to access the prototype.  Then I'd have it call back to an event-handling function that's actually properly part of the Map object.  Here's what that might look like:

in the inner loop of the `render` function:

```
                var map = this;
                cell.addEventListener("click", function () {
                     map.cellClicked (this);
                }, false);
                cell.x = x; cell.y = y;
```

and the new `cellClicked` function:

```
Map.prototype = {
   cellClicked: function (cell) {
      this.render (cell.x - 1, cell.y - 1);
   },
```

Comment: Inside of `move`, `this` references the element that triggers the click event, not the `Map` object.

Comment: Then why is `move` a method of the `Map` object?  Either define it inline when you set the event handler, or put it in an object of its own.  Declaring it as part of the Map means people will assume that `this` is supposed to refer to the Map when it executes.

Comment: Also, you still shouldn't be referring to `Map.prototype` like that: when you execute a method on `Map.prototype` any changes it makes to `this` affect *all instances* of `Map`, not just one.  I'll post an update that shows how I would handle this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it wrong.

It seems massive overkill to re-generate a table and attach listeners every time you move, while you could simply update the `textContent` of the cells.

If you had an HTML table like this:

```
<table>
  <tr><td id="0,0"></td><td id="1,0"></td><td id="2,0"></td></tr>
  <tr><td id="0,1"></td><td id="1,1"></td><td id="2,1"></td></tr>
  <tr><td id="0,1"></td><td id="1,2"></td><td id="2,2"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Then your render routine could be as simple as

```
render:function() {
   var viewRow, viewColumn, element;
   //Loop over view and update text content
   for (viewRow = 0; viewRow < this.viewRows; viewRow++) {
     for (viewColumn = 0; viewColumn < this.viewCols; viewColumn++) {
       element = document.getElementById( viewColumn + ',' + viewRow )
       element.textContent = ( viewColumn + this.col - 1 ) + ',' + ( viewRow + this.row - 1 );
     }
   }
}
```

Where `this.row` and `this.col` represent the center cell the player is on.

I will leave the event handling to you, but I would suggest to add each cell the vector values ( so top left is (-1,-1 ) ) and from there calculate the new `this.row` and `this.col` and then re-render the map.